# IDA remote GDB debugger cannot suspend linux machine

Tags: ida, gdb

I am starting Debugging Linux Virtual Machine by IDA GDB debugger. I can say I am able to connect to **process (0)** and start the machine (by using IDA 32bit,  IMO it has something to do with bios! or I don't know at all!).

- But after starting it I cannot get data back to IDA. when I try to suspend the machine via IDA it won't work at all and takes so long time without any chance.
- I also tried connecting to the machine via another IDA instance by a 64bit version of IDA and I can only connect to **process (1)** which breaks the line to debug processes already running!

Could someone help a bit on this tricky thing?